# Open file inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a noob question.
I need to do the class, which in init opening file and other function just appending to this opened file text. How I can do this?
Need to do something like this, but this is not working, so help.

file1.py

```
from logsystem import LogginSystem as logsys

file_location='/tmp/test'
file = logsys(file_location)
file.write('some message')
```

file2.py

```
class LogginSystem(object):

    def __init__(self, file_location):
        self.log_file = open(file_location, 'a+')

    def write(self, message):
        self.log_file.write(message)
```

Thanks

Comment: Override `__del__()` and close the stream with: `self.log_file.close()` (it will be automatically flushed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like *zwer* already mentioned, you could use the `__del__()` method to achieve this behaviour.

`__del__` is the Python equivalent of a destructor, and is called when the object is garbage collected. It is **not** guaranteed though that the object will actually be garbage collected (this is implementation dependent)!

Another, more safe approach would be the use of the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods which can be implemented in the following way:

```py
class LogginSystem(object):

def __enter__(self, file_location):
    self.log_file = open(file_location, 'a+')
    return self

def write(self, message):
    self.log_file.write(message)

def __exit__(self):
    self.log_file.close()
```

This allows you to use the `with`-statement for automatic cleanup:

```py
from logsystem import LogginSystem as logsys

file_location='/tmp/test'
with logsys(file_location) as file:
    file.write('some message')
```

You can read more about these methods, and the `with`-statement [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 1):

Files provide a context manager for use in `with` statements so the file is automaticlly closed when you are done with it.

You can leverage that in a class by deriving from `contextlib.ExitStack` like this:

```
class LogginSystem(contextlib.ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, file_location, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.logfile = self.enter_context(open(file_location))

    def write(self, message):
        self.log_file.write(message)
```